# prematch for replace html tags

Tags: php, preg-replace, preg-match-all

Using preg match to pick

```
<table align='center' id='tbl_currency'> <tr> <span class=bld>631.0075 USD</span>
```

just i want to pick this number and currency 631.0075 USD

This number and currency is dynamic   ,

Is it possible ,

Comment: You might want to fix the string above. The way it is now, it is not HTML and even with the angle brackets in place, the HTML would be invalid, because a tr may not contain span elements

Comment: Alas, it looks like HTML and that is sufficient for most web developers. =)

Answer (score 1):

Never use regex, always use a parser:

```
$htmlfragment = "<table align='center' id='tbl_currency'> <tr> <td><span class=bld>631.0075 USD</span></td></tr></table>";

$domdoc = new DomDocument();
$domdoc->loadHTML($htmlfragment);

$xpath = new DOMXPath($domdoc);
$result = $xpath->query("//table[@id='tbl_currency']//span[@class='bld']");

if ($result->length > 0) {
  $currency_span = $result->item(0);
  print $currency_span->nodeValue;
} else {
  print "nothing found";
}
```

prints

```
631.0075 USD
```

Wrap that in a function and you are good to go.

You might want to skim through [an XPath tutorial](http://www.w3schools.com/xpath/default.asp) if you've never use XPath before.

Answer (score 0):

Using regular expressions to extract data from HTML sources is frowned at at stackoverflow. Please consider using a html parser for this task (e.g. [SimpleHTMLDom](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/)).

If you want to do this once, and quick and very dirty, maybe you can get away with something like

```
"<span class=bld>([^<]*)</span>"
```

This assumes that all and only all the currency values you are interested in are contained in span tags, with class bld and no other attributes.